# How can I get rows that compouse up to 90% of a sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two different dataframes, one containing the Net Revenue by SKU and Supplier and another one containing the stock of SKUs in each store. I need to get an average by Supplier of the stores that contains the SKUs that compouse up to 90% the net revenue of the supplier. It's a bit complicated but I will exemplify, and I hope it can make it clear. Please, note that if 3 SKUs compose 89% of the revenue, we need to consider another one.

Example:

Dataframe 1 - Net Revenue

| Supplier | SKU | Net Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNILEVER | 1111 | 10000 |
| UNILEVER | 2222 | 50000 |
| UNILEVER | 3333 | 500 |
| PEPSICO | 1313 | 680 |
| PEPSICO | 2424 | 10000 |
| PEPSICO | 2323 | 450 |

Dataframe 2 - Stock

| Store | SKU | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 1 |
| 1 | 2222 | 2 |
| 1 | 3333 | 1 |
| 2 | 1111 | 1 |
| 2 | 2222 | 0 |
| 2 | 3333 | 1 |

In this case, for UNILEVER, we need to discard SKU 3333 because its net revenue is not relevant (as 1111 and 2222 already compouse more than 90% of the total net revenue of UNILEVER).  Coverage in this case will be 1.5 (we have 1111 in 2 stores and 2222 in one store: (1+2)/2).

Result is something like this:

| Supplier | Coverage |
| --- | --- |
| UNILEVER | 1.5 |
| PEPSICO | ... |

Please, note that the real dataset has a different number of SKUs by supplier and a huge number of suppliers (around 150), so performance doesn't need to be PRIORITY but it has to be considered.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the cumulative sum grouping by Suppler and divide by the Supplier Total Revenue.

Then find each Supplier Revenue Threshold by getting the minimum Cumulative Revenue Percentage under 90%.

Then you can get the list of SKUs by Supplier and calculate the coverage.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['UNILEVER', '1111', 10000], 
    ['UNILEVER', '2222', 50000], 
    ['UNILEVER', '3333', 500], 
    ['PEPSICO', '1313', 680], 
    ['PEPSICO', '2424', 10000], 
    ['PEPSICO', '2323', 450], 
], columns=['Supplier', 'SKU', 'Net Revenue'])

total_revenue_by_supplier = df.groupby(df['Supplier']).sum().reset_index()
total_revenue_by_supplier.columns = ['Supplier', 'Total Revenue']

df = df.sort_values(['Supplier', 'Net Revenue'], ascending=[True, False])

df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(df['Supplier'])['Net Revenue'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)

df = df.merge(total_revenue_by_supplier, on='Supplier')

df['cumpercentage'] = df['cumsum'] / df['Total Revenue']

min_before_threshold = df[df['cumpercentage'] >= 0.9][['Supplier', 'cumpercentage']].groupby('Supplier').min().reset_index()
min_before_threshold.columns = ['Supplier', 'Revenue Threshold']

df = df.merge(min_before_threshold, on='Supplier')

df = df[df['cumpercentage'] <= df['Revenue Threshold']][['Supplier', 'SKU', 'Net Revenue']]

df
```